# How to make the scrollbar scroll down in discord server using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, discord

I am currently working on a python selenium bot that chats on discord servers automatically. But I am facing a problem. It works fine but after sometimes in discord, it shows "You are viewing old messages Jump to present". So I figured out to periodically move the scroll bar down to end of the page. But I tried everything the scroll bar doesn't move down to end of the page. Can you guys help me figure out the code?

Here is what all I tried to move scrollbar down but it doesn't work.

```
1. driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
2. driver.find_element_by_class_name('scrollbar-element').send_keys(Keys.END)
3. driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-1000);")
```

Comment: I would recommend using the discord API, check this out: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro. I have used both selenium and the discord bot API extensively, and the API is a much better tool.

Comment: It is actualy a bot that chats on other server not mine. You cant do that type of bots using discord bot API

Comment: Ah yes, if the server does not give the bot access/subscribe to it, then you cannot do that using the API.'

Comment: Exactly :) thats the reason i went with selenium. But i cant figure out how to make the bot scroll to present messages

Comment: executeScript("window.scroll(0, document.height);");